# degree theory for elliptic equations; special solutions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am interested in using degree theory to examine some semilinear problems. 
But instead of just looking for solutions lets assume i am looking for a certain class of solutions; for instance lets consider just stable solutions.   Is there some way to adjust the usual degree theory so that it can be applied in the restricted class of solutions? I realize this is a somewhat vague question, but any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of degree theory is its topological invariance. Now consider a saddle node bifurcation where you have a change from no solution to a stable and an unstable solution. This example should be enough to convince you that a "degree" which counts only stable solutions cannot exist.

Comment: thanks for the comment... (I symbol pushed a bit with some elliptic pde's i know and came to the same conclusion... but i thought there may be some hope for something else.... I guess not).   thats for your answer